# How to find the energy of a rect signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-energy

Given a signal
$$
x(t)=-2\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac t4\right)
$$

- What is the energy of signal $-x(t + 1)$?
- What are the steps needed to find the energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a definition of the energy of a signal from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_(signal_processing)
For your specific signal, I recommend to draw the original signal and then the transformation. Finally, just calculate the squared magnitude and the area under it.

These are plots of the steps I mentioned (from Matlab):
[image]

As you can see in the last plot, the energy is basically the area under the rectangle, which is in this case 4*4=16.